# Scrapy view redirect to other page and get <400> error

Tags: view, scrapy, fetch, response

I am trying to do scrapy view or fetch https://www.watsons.com.sg and the page will be redirected and return <400> error. Wonder if there is anyway to work around it. The log shows something like this:

```
2018-11-15 22:54:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-15 22:54:15 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-15 22:54:15 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-11-15 22:54:15 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://queue.watsons.com.sg?c=aswatson&e=watsonprdsg&ver=v3-java-3.5.2&cver=55&cid=zh-CN&l=PoC+Layout+SG&t=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.watsons.com.sg%2F> from **<GET https://www.watsons.com.sg>
2018-11-15 22:54:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400)** <GET https://queue.watsons.com.sg?c=aswatson&e=watsonprdsg&ver=v3-java-3.5.2&cver=55&cid=zh-CN&l=PoC+Layout+SG&t=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.watsons.com.sg%2F> (referer: None)
2018-11-15 22:54:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

If I use request.get("https://www.watsons.com.sg") its fine. Any idea or comment much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is one of the weird behaviors of `scrapy`.

If you look at the `location` header in the HTTP response (with Firefox developer tools for example), you can see:

```
location: https://queue.watsons.com.sg?c=aswatson&e=watsonprdsg&ver=v3-java-3.5.2&cver=55&cid=zh-CN&l=PoC+Layout+SG&t=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.watsons.com.sg%2F
```

Note that there is no `/` between the `.com.sg` and the `?`.

Looking at how Firefox behaves, on the next request it adds the missing `/`:

[image: Firefox adds the missing slash]

However, somehow scrapy does not do it!
If you look at your logs, when the HTTP 400 error is received, we can see that the `/` is missing.

This is being discussed in this issue: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1133

For now, the way I go around it is to have my own downloader middleware that normalizes the `location` header, before the response is being passed in the redirect middleware.

It looks like this:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from w3lib.url import safe_download_url

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = 'watsons.com.sg'
    start_urls = ['https://www.watsons.com.sg/']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'spiders.myspider.FixLocationHeaderMiddleWare': 650
        }
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        pass

class FixLocationHeaderMiddleWare:

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if 'location' in response.headers:
            response.headers['location'] = safe_download_url(response.headers['location'].decode())
        return response
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and help. I tried integrated the code in my original .py as well as running the suggested code as individual .py using scrapy runspider but it always result in "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spiders' ". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You need to replace `spiders.myspider` by your own module name.

Comment: So if my code is "class WatsonsSpider(scrapy.Spider):" then I should use "'spiders.WatsonsSpider.FixLocationHeaderMiddleWare': 650"   Strange it cant seem to work...

Comment: What is your folder and `.py` files structure?

Comment: I think I didn't trigger the middleware correctly. Let me read more about it and try again. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickChan please look at my answer in https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3494#issuecomment-447553834, and kindly mask my answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: I needed to be more explicit with the path in my 'custom_settings'.
My spider's file name is landingpage004_scraper, so I thought I could do:
`custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'spiders.landingpage004_scraper.FixLocationHeaderMiddleWare': 650
        }
    }`

But it wouldn't work. I had to include the project name, which is 'LandingPageVerifier'. This is what worked for me:

`'custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
      'LandingPageVerifier.spiders.landingpage004_scraper.FixLocationHeaderMiddleWare': 650
        }
    }'`

Comment: @Guillaume I finally got the suggestions implemented correctly. I did a print in the code and confirmed "/" is being added to the response object. However the 400 error issue is still there as per scrapy log: 2019-01-01 21:17:15 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 [link](https://queue.watsons.com.sg/?c=aswatson&e=watsonprdsg&ver=v3-java-3.5.2&cver=62&cid=zh-CN&l=PoC+Layout+SG&t=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.watsons.com.sg%2F>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed). Wonder what is causing the 400 error....